# How to find parents based on child fields in mongo using aggregation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is a code I have:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const Box = require('./models/Box')

const boxesToBePicked = await Box.find({ status: 'ready', client: 27 })
const boxesOriginalIds = _(boxesToBePicked).map('original').compact().uniq().value()
const boxesOriginal = boxesOriginalIds.length ? await Box.find({ _id: { $in: boxesOriginalIds } }) : []

const attributes = ['name']

const boxes = [
  ...boxesOriginal,
  ...boxesToBePicked.filter(box => !box.original)
].map(box => _.pick(box, attributes))
```

Let's say, we have following data in "boxes" collection:

```
[
  { _id: 1, name: 'Original Box #1', status: 'pending' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 1 },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 1 },
  { _id: 4, name: 'Nested box', status: 'pending', original: 1 },
  { _id: 5, name: 'Original Box #2', status: 'ready' },
  { _id: 6, name: 'Original Box #3', status: 'pending' },
  { _id: 7, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 6 },
  { _id: 8, name: 'Original Box #4', status: 'pending' }
]
```

Workflow

Find all boxes, which are ready to be picked:

```
const boxesToBePicked = await Box.find({ status: 'ready' })

// Returns:

[
  { _id: 2, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 1 },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 1 },
  { _id: 5, name: 'Original Box #2', status: 'ready' },
  { _id: 7, name: 'Nested box', status: 'ready', original: 6 }
]
```

Get all the IDs of original (parent) boxes of those:

```
const boxesOriginalIds = _(boxesToBePicked).map('original').compact().uniq().value()

// Returns:

[1, 6]
```

Get those boxes by their IDs:

```
const boxesOriginal = boxesOriginalIds.length ? await Box.find({ _id: { $in: boxesOriginalIds } }) : []

// Returns

[
  { _id: 1, name: 'Original Box #1', status: 'pending' },
  { _id: 6, name: 'Original Box #3', status: 'pending' }
]
```

Join those boxes with not nested boxes to be picked:

```
const boxes = [
  ...boxesOriginal,
  ...boxesToBePicked.filter(box => !box.original)
].map(box => _.pick(box, attributes))

// Returns

[
  { name: 'Original Box #1' },
  { name: 'Original Box #3' },
  { name: 'Original Box #2' }
]
```

So basically what we are doing here is getting all the original boxes if they have at least one nested box with status "ready", and all not nested boxes with status "ready".

I think it can be simplified by using aggregation pipeline and projection. But how?

Answer (score 2):

To decompose the aggregation :

- a `$group` which creates

  - an array `ids` which match ready `status` for which it will add the `*original` value
  - an array `box_ready` which match ready `status` and keep the other fields as is (it will be used later)
  - an array `document` which contain the whole original document (`$$ROOT`)

    ```
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$status", "ready"] },
                        "$original", null
                    ]
                }
            },
            box_ready: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$status", "ready"] },
                        { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", original: "$original", status: "$status" },
                        null
                    ]
                }
            },
            document: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
    ```
- `$unwind` document field to remove the array

  ```
  {
      $unwind: "$document"
  }
  ```
- use a `$redact` aggregation to keep or remove records based on matching of `$document._id` in the array `ids` previously created (that contain the matching `original` and `status`)

  ```
  {
      $redact: {
          "$cond": {
              "if": {
                  "$setIsSubset": [{
                          "$map": {
                              "input": { "$literal": ["A"] },
                              "as": "a",
                              "in": "$document._id"
                          }
                      },
                      "$ids"
                  ]
              },
              "then": "$$KEEP",
              "else": "$$PRUNE"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `$group` to push all documents that matched the previous `$redact` to another array named `filtered` (we have now 2 array which can be united)

  ```
  {
      $group: {
          _id: null,
          box_ready: { $first: "$box_ready" },
          filtered: { $push: "$document" }
      }
  }
  ```
- use a `$project` with a `setUnion` to union the arrays `box_ready` and `filtered`

  ```
  {
      $project: {
          union: {
              $setUnion: ["$box_ready", "$filtered"]
          },
          _id: 0
      }
  }
  ```
- `$unwind` the array you have obtained to get distinct records

  ```
  {
      $unwind: "$union"
  }
  ```
- `$match` only those which have `original` missing and that are not null (as initially a the status:ready condition has obliged to get a null value on the first `$group`

  ```
  {
      $match: {
          "union.original": {
              "$exists": false
          },
          "union": { $nin: [null] }
      }
  }
  ```

The whole aggregation query is :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$status", "ready"] },
                        "$original", null
                    ]
                }
            },
            box_ready: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$status", "ready"] },
                        { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", original: "$original", status: "$status" },
                        null
                    ]
                }
            },
            document: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$document"
    }, {
        $redact: {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$setIsSubset": [{
                            "$map": {
                                "input": { "$literal": ["A"] },
                                "as": "a",
                                "in": "$document._id"
                            }
                        },
                        "$ids"
                    ]
                },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }, {

        $group: {
            _id: null,
            box_ready: { $first: "$box_ready" },
            filtered: { $push: "$document" }
        }

    }, {
        $project: {
            union: {
                $setUnion: ["$box_ready", "$filtered"]
            },
            _id: 0
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$union"
    }, {
        $match: {
            "union.original": {
                "$exists": false
            },
            "union": { $nin: [null] }
        }
    }]
)
```

It gives you :

```
{ "union" : { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Original Box #1", "status" : "pending" } }
{ "union" : { "_id" : 5, "name" : "Original Box #2", "status" : "ready" } }
{ "union" : { "_id" : 6, "name" : "Original Box #3", "status" : "pending" } }
```

Use an additional `$project` if you want to select specific fields

For `mongoose`, you should be able to do like this to perform aggregation :

```
Box.aggregate([
    //the whole aggregation here
], function(err, result) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks pretty complicated. I am pretty sure this code can be simplified.

Comment: I can't believe that something that's easily done in EF/LINQ can be so hard in Mongo

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below. Uses $lookUp to self join to collection and $match stage with $or in combination with $and for second condition and the next part of $or for first condition and $group stage to remove duplicates and $project stage to format the response.

```
db.boxes.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "boxes",
        localField: "original",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "nested_orders"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$nested_orders",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        $or: [{
            $and: [{
                "status": "ready"
            }, {
                "nested_orders": {
                    $exists: false,
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "nested_orders.status": "pending"
        }]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "names": {
            $addToSet: {
                name: "$name",
                nested_name: "$nested_orders.name"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$names"
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": {
            $ifNull: ['$names.nested_name', '$names.name']
        }
    }
}]).pretty();
```

Sample Response

```
{ "name" : "Original Box #1" }
{ "name" : "Original Box #2" }
{ "name" : "Original Box #3" }
```

Comment: I think $lookup as a first operation will be pretty heavy in terms of performance as it will consider all the boxes in the collection.

Comment: It depends on the size of your input collection and may be you can apply filter to limit the input going into lookup stage. I'll recommend performance testing the solution for your data. Btw updated answer to match the expected response.

Comment: you have the right idea, but in the wrong order which makes it too complex.  You should first accumulate _ids of boxes to be picked up and *then* rehydrate them with their name using $lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Several of the answers are close but here's the most efficient way.  It accumulates the "_id" values of boxes to be picked up and then uses `$lookup` to "rehydrate" the full details of each (top-level) box.

```
db.boxes.aggregate(
    {$group: {
         _id:null, 
         boxes:{$addToSet:{$cond:{
            if:{$eq:["$status","ready"]},
            then:{$ifNull:["$original","$_id"]},
            else:null
         }}}
    }},

    {$lookup: {
          from:"boxes",
          localField:"boxes",
          foreignField:"_id",
          as:"boxes"
    }}
)
```

Your result based on sample data:

```
{
"_id" : null,
"boxIdsToPickUp" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Original Box #1",
        "status" : "pending"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 5,
        "name" : "Original Box #2",
        "status" : "ready"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 6,
        "name" : "Original Box #3",
        "status" : "pending"
    }
] }
```

Note that the `$lookup` is done only for the `_id` values of boxes to be picked up which is far more efficient than doing it for all boxes.

If you wanted the pipeline to be *more* efficient you would need to store more details about original box in the nested box documents (like its name).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you can follow bellow steps:

> 1. First of all select record for **status is ready** (because you want to get parent who has no nested box but *status is ready* and who
>      has nested box at least one with *stats is ready* )
> 2. Find parent box using `$lookup`
> 3. then `$group` to get unique parent box
> 4. then `$project` box name

So can try this query:

```
db.getCollection('boxes').aggregate(
        {$match:{"status":'ready'}},
        {$lookup: {from: "boxes", localField: "original", foreignField: "_id", as: "parent"}},
        {$unwind: {path: "$parent",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
        {$group:{
                _id:null,
                list:{$addToSet:{"$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$parent.name", false] }, {name:"$parent.name"}, {name:"$name"} ]}}
                }
        },
        {$project:{name:"$list.name", _id:0}},
        {$unwind: "$name"}
 )
```

**OR**

> 1. get record for status is ready
> 2. get desired recordID
> 3. get name according to recordID

```
db.getCollection('boxes').aggregate(
        {$match:{"status":'ready'}},
        {$group:{
                _id:null,
                parent:{$addToSet:{"$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$original", false] }, "$original", "$_id" ]}}
                }
        },
        {$unwind:"$parent"},
        {$lookup: {from: "boxes", localField: "parent", foreignField: "_id", as: "parent"}},
        {$project: {"name" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$parent.name", 0 ] }, _id:0}}
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using mongoose (4.x)

Schema:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    ....
    status: String,
    original: { type: Number, ref: 'Box'}
});
const Box = mongoose.model('Box', schema);
```

Actual Query:

```
Box
    .find({ status: 'ready' })
    .populate('original')
    .exec((err, boxes) => {
        if (err) return;
        boxes = boxes.map((b) => b.original ? b.original : b);
        boxes = _.uniqBy(boxes, '_id');
        console.log(boxes);
    });
```

Docs on Mongoose#populate: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html